# MVVM Light DataGrid binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid, mvvm-light

I'm developing a WPF with C#, .NET Framework 4.5.1, MVVM Light framework and Entity Framework 6.1.3.

I have this `DataGrid` in a window:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="LevelConfigurationDataGrid" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,0" ItemsSource="{Binding LevelConfigs}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CODE_LEVE}" Header="Nivel"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CODE_NAME}" Header="Nombre"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IS_ACTIVE}" Header="¿Activa?"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CODE_TYPE}" Header="Tipo de código"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CODE_SOURCE}" Header="Origen del código"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding HELPER_CODE_TYPE}" Header="Tipo de Helper Code"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding HELPER_CODE_SOURCE}" Header="Origen del helper code"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding QUANTITY}" Header="Cantidad"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding REMAINING_CODES}" Header="Restantes"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TRZ_ENDPOINT}" Header="TRZ IP"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TRZ_ENDPORT}" Header="TRZ Puerto"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And on `MainViewModel`:

```
public ObservableCollection<CODE_LEVEL_CONFIGURATION> LevelConfigs
{
    get { return m_LevelConfigs; }
    set
    {
        m_LevelConfigs = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("LevelConfigs");
    }
}
```

And on `CODE_LEVEL_CONFIGURATION`:

```
public class CODE_LEVEL_CONFIGURATION
{
    public byte CODE_LEVEL { get; set; }
    public string LEVEL_NAME { get; set; }
    public bool IS_ACTIVE { get; set; }
    public byte CODE_TYPE { get; set; }
    public byte CODE_SOURCE { get; set; }
    public byte? HELPER_CODE_TYPE { get; set; }
    public byte? HELPER_CODE_SOURCE { get; set; }
    public int QUANTITY { get; set; }
    public int REMAINING_CODES { get; set; }
    public string TRZ_ENDPOINT { get; set; }
    public int? TRZ_ENDPORT { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CODES> Codes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HELPER_CODES> HelperCodes { get; set; }
}
```

But, when I load the data on `DataGrid` I get more columns that I have defined on `XAML`. I get my columns and 13 columns more (on for each `CODE_LEVEL_CONFIGURATION` property).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting [AutoGenerateColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to False

```
<DataGrid x:Name="LevelConfigurationDataGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,0" ItemsSource="{Binding LevelConfigs}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```